# How to update the status within the listview row?

Tags: c#

I have a listview. So when I click on `Abort` button, status should change from `" Sent/received"` to `"Aborted"` and at the same time, Aborted proposals should disappear from the listview. Note that Only status of  Sent/Received proposals should display in a listview.

What I wanted to do is after clicking on `abort button`, the status should change to Aborted and at the same time, the whole row should disappear from the listview.

[image]

Here I tried to update the status of website `www.tryu.com` from `sent/received to Aborted`, but it's not getting change.

I have used the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!IsPostBack)
        //{
        //    CheckUserLogin();
        //}

        CheckUserLogin();
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            getProposalNotification();
            GetBartersCount();
        }

    }

   protected void getProposalNotification()
    {

        MySqlConnection connect = null;
        try
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarterConnectionString"].ToString();
            connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            string uid = Session["session_barterUser_id"].ToString();
            string queryStr = "SELECT pro_id,comp_name,website,bw.name,sent_date,proposal_status from barter_proposals bp, barter_company be,barter_websites bw WHERE bp.company=be.comp_id and bp.website_a=bw.web_id and user_id=?uid and proposal_status!='Completed' and proposal_status!='Aborted' order by pro_id desc ";

            connect.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, connect);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?uid", uid);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            // command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lstvwProNotify.DataSource = dt;
                lstvwProNotify.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                lstvwProNotify.DataSource = null;
            }
            connect.Close();

        }
        catch { }
    }

    protected void AbortStatus(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connect = null;
        try {

            ListViewItem item = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
            Button buttReminder = (Button)item.FindControl("btnAbort");
            Int64 pid = Convert.ToInt64(buttReminder.CommandArgument);
            //Label id = (Label)((Button)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("lblId");
            Label status = (Label)((Button)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("lblStatus");

            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarterConnectionString"].ToString();
            connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE barter_proposals SET proposal_status=@Status WHERE  pro_id=@ID", connect);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", pid);
           // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Aborted");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status","Aborted");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           // connect.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
        //this.BindList();
        getProposalNotification();
    }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Have you use SP for this?

Comment: @Haytam..Problem is status is not getting updated from sent/received to Aborted

Comment: @KiranJoshi..no..i have not used sp

Comment: Most likely that your data is saved, only page is not refreshed. You either need to refresh a page after button clicking or come up with some javascript that will update the status.

Comment: But where are you changing the status though? in your listview.

Comment: @Haytam...After clicking on abort button,the status "Sent/Received" should change to "Aborted" and at the same time it should disappear from that listview.

Comment: Yes but how can you change it and remove it? Its either one or the other, if you change the status and remove the item then you wouldn't see the status changing...

Comment: @Haytam...there is Dashboard module where the listview contains all the proposals of the status "Sent/received". so when i will change it to "Aborted",it should disappear and there is some other module as "view proposals",where all the proposal of the status ie. "Sent/received","completed","aborted" is showing.So the aborted proposal from dashboard will go to view proposal module.thats why i have used sqlquery in getpropsalnotification() method.

Comment: @trailmax...should i use updatepanel for it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're wondering how to remove that row after changing its status to "Aborted" in the database?

If so, you simply do:

```
item.Remove();
```

Since you have the `ListViewItem` instance.

Comment: ..if the status bcmes Aborted,it will automatically disappear from the listview as dashboard contains all the sent/received status proposal set by the query.my problem is it is not getting updated from sent/received to aborted.